# CDC with SSIS: process all changes in order of occurrence

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis, change-data-capture, ssis-2012

I have a SSIS package that I'm using to sync (in an on going basis) all changes from one table to another. Note that I need to sync **ALL** changes and not just **NET** changes.

**My problem** is that I cannot figure out how to process the changes in the same order that they occurred in on the source table.

As a starting place, I used [CDC in SSIS for SQL Server 2012](http://www.mattmasson.com/2011/12/cdc-in-ssis-for-sql-server-2012-2/). The Control Flow for my setup looks like:

[image]

And the data flow looks like:

[image]

The above setup is working for syncing all changes, just not in the correct order. Reading [Processing Modes for the CDC Source](http://www.mattmasson.com/2012/01/processing-modes-for-the-cdc-source/), two relevant points are made:

- "The order that the operations took place can be determined by the
  __$seqval field"
- "You will (typically) not want to use the CDC Splitter when processing all changes, as sending your change rows down multiple paths will make it difficult to apply them in the correct order."

So that's definitely my issue. Does anyone know how I can process the changes from the CDC Source in the correct order? I have not been able to find any examples online and I'm somewhat new to SSIS.